# Calling a script not in the same path

Tags: bash, shell-script

Let's say I have a bash script located in `/home/user/examples` that works as follows (it simply takes the user inputted number and adds it to itself ) :

```
[user]$ add 
Enter a number: 10

results:
entered value - 10
new value - 20
```

And I want to create another bash script located in `/home/user/other` that takes an argument that is given and uses it as the number for the add script from above, but only prints the new value. For example:

```
[user]$ organize 10

New Value
20
```

How do I go about this?

Comment: Just a side note, you are using too many spaces in your example. Fixing again.

Answer (score 2):

The simple answer is

```
printf '%s\n' "$1" | /home/user/examples/scriptname.sh | sed -n -e '$ s/^new value - // p'
```

The more thoroughly correct answer is to write an `expect` script that looks for the prompt (`Enter a number:`), sends "$1" and <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and then extracts the result.

Comment: FYI, this is a good object lesson on why unix CLI tools tend to be very terse and why they tend to take input on the command line (and/or stdin) rather than asking questions of the user, and why they print just the bare results (without any excess or non-essential verbiage) as output: so it can be easily re-used by other tools.